# How to convert Java code to mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to convert my Java code to Hadoop MapReduce.
I am new to MapReduce programming so can you please help me out with this.

I am trying to take count of all the distinct values in my file, and present the output in another file.

Input:
Alex
Alex
John
Stuart
Michael
John
Michael
Alex

Output:
Alex 3

John 2

Stuart 1

Michael 2

Here's my code:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] arr = { "sa", "pa" , "ga", "sa", "pa", "la" };
        String[] result = new String[10];
        int counter = 0, count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            boolean isDistinct = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    isDistinct = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isDistinct) {
                result[counter++] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (result[i] == arr[j]) {
                    count++;
                }

            }
            System.out.println(result[i] + " = " + count);

        }
    }
}
```

In this code I have given input as an array, but in actual circumstances I need to fetch that from a file in HDFS.

Plus output of the file should be in making a new file in HDFS.

Comment: You should have found an answer by some research

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is equivalent to the standard WordCount MapReduce example most developers will start with.

[Example: WordCount v1.0](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0)

WordCount is a single MapReduce job with a Map and Reduce stage.

The Mapper reads each line from an input file, one at a time. It emits a key which is the value (in your case a name) and a count of 1.

The Reduce groups based on the Key (name) and adds up the values, finally emitting a key and the total number of times that key has been seen.

You'll notice the example includes a Combine stage which (basically) runs on the output of the Mapper. In this example the Reduce can be reused since the logic is the same and it receives and emits the same types of key/value objects. The combiner will reduce the amount of data sent to the Reduce stage.